# Chart.Js -"Cannot read property 'datasets' of undefined" when trying to update chart

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I've looked into quite a few threads on here regarding how to dynamically update chart.js charts. I've tried to follow the answers as best I can, however every time I try to update the chart periodically with data from my database i get the aforementioned error.

I declare `sentimentMainContent`, which is to be the chart object when the page is fully loaded. Within the document ready function the `getStatsUpdate` function exists, which makes periodic calls to a database to retrieve data regarding the positive and negative sentiment for the home and away team for a game of football.
Upon retrieving the data, it will first create the chart (it does this when `statsRenderCount` is 0), and will subsequently update it. It does the first part of creating the graph with the data from the initial call correctly, however subsequent calls will enter the else statement and try to update the chart. Here I receive the ***"Cannot read property 'datasets' of undefined"*** error.

As far as my understanding goes, it's as if it isn't recognising that `sentimentMainContent` exists, as if it doesn't exist within its scope, however I know this can't be correct, as I've declared it at the very start of the document ready load function, within which `getStatsUpdate()` sits. So `sentimentMainContent` can't be undefined, surely?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var sentimentMainContent = 0;
    ...
    ...
    ...
function getStatsUpdate(){
    ...
    var result = initialResponse.split("___");
tweet_time = result[0]
home_avg = result[1];
home_positive = result[2];
home_negative = result[3];
home_neutral = result[4];

away_avg = result[5];
away_positive = result[6];
away_negative = result[7];
away_neutral = result[8];

var home_sentiment = {
                        labels: [
                            homeTeam + " Positive",
                            homeTeam + " Negative",
                            awayTeam + " Positive",
                            awayTeam + " Negative",
                        ],
                        datasets: [
                            {
                                data: [home_positive, home_negative, away_positive, away_negative],
                                backgroundColor: [
                                    "#F5003F",
                                    "#3C9BFF",
                                    "#26FF9A",
                                    "#FFE951"
                                ],
                                borderColor: [
                                    "black",
                                    "black",
                                    "black",
                                    "black",
                                    "black",
                                    "black"
                                ],
                                borderWidth: [
                                    "0.5",
                                    "0.5",
                                    "0.5",
                                    "0.5",
                                    "0.5",
                                    "0.5",
                                ],
                                hoverBackgroundColor: [
                                    "#F5003F",
                                    "#FAFAFA",
                                    "#3C9BFF",
                                    "#26FF9A",
                                    "#FF5720",
                                    "#FFE951"
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    };

if(statsRenderCount == 0)
{
    alert("re-rendering!");
    sentimentMainContent = new Chart(document.getElementById("sentiment-stat"), {
        type: 'doughnut',
        data: home_sentiment,
        options: {
                cutoutPercentage: 60,
                responsive: true,
                legend: {
                    display: false
            },
            tooltips: {
                filter: function(item, home_sentiment) {
                    var label = home_sentiment.labels[item.index];
                    if (label) return item;
                }
            }
        }
    });
    statsRenderCount += 1;
}
else
{
    alert("updating");
    sentimentMainContent.home_sentiment.datasets[0] = home_sentiment;
    sentimentMainContent.update();
}
}
```

I also tried `sentimentMainContent.home_sentiment = home_sentiment;` as it seemed that the approach was flawed in that `sentimentMainContent.home_sentiment.datasets[0]` represents the datasets array, and I was assigning to this the entire home_sentiment variable, which seemed incorrect. Regardless, when I make this change, no error occurs, however the chart doesn't update at all.

Is there something glaringly obvious I'm overlooking here?